# How to redirect stderr in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: redirect, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, stderr

I have this in my Jenkinsfile:

```
sh 'cat /opt/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsfileTest/testfile 2>/dev/null
```

but it actually runs like this:

```
[JenkinsfileTest] Running shell script
+ cat /opt/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsfileTest/testfile
```

the redirection part is gone.

Is there anything wrong with my command?

Comment: What `+` signs indicate is the debugging output from `bash -x`, so it's possible it is showing pieces of the command rather than the full line depending on how it is evaluated (try also pipes like `cat ... | tee somefile.log` to check)

Comment: I want `2>/dev/null` because sometimes the `/opt/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsfileTest/testfile` does not exist. This is acceptable. But I don't want it to output `No such file or directory` when the file does not exist. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `test -e JenkinsfileTest/testfile && any_command` will only execute `any_command` if the file exists

Comment: This meets my requirement. I thought too much.